# Streaming audio on Android with QPython

Tags: android, python-2.7, audio, streaming, qpython

I have created a simple code that plays the latest podcast from BBC World Service. On Linux I rely on MPlayer to stream the file. How can I do the same on QPython running under Android?

```
import urllib
import subprocess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def bbc_news():

  print("Collecting Podcast Episode...")

  r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p02nq0gn/episodes/downloads')
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

  links = soup.select('a.link-complex.br-linkinvert.buttons__download__link')

  print(links[0].get('download'))

  subprocess.call("mplayer "+ links[0].get('href'), shell=True)

def main():

  bbc_news()

  return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Basically, do urllib and beautiful soup work in QPython/Android? 
And which component could replace mplayer as mp3-file streamer?